# Skrill payment gateway integration in android

Tags: android, skrill

I want to integrate skrill payment gateway in one of my application. I am not able to find any solution. Please help if anybody have any idea.

Comment: What specifically have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I have used paypal payment gateway. Paypal SDK is available. But i didn't find any SDK for skrill. I don't know how to proceed. Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Even thought there is no such SDK, you can aways redirect the customer to skrill through the browse or simple within your app. 
Once you prepare the request with prepare_only=1 , you just get back a sid and you can simple redirect with the sid to skrill => /app/payment.pl?sid="the_returned_sid"
The status_url is handled on the server side anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a one way to integrate skrill with android aap.
you have to program your web server for it in php . and send post commands to that web server link through your android app.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code in order to further improve your answer?